# How to know if two methods do the same thing on different representations of the same data

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have two different matrix representations.

**Matrix saved as array** `float*`:

```
| 1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0  7.0   8.0   9.0 |
```

**And as array of array** `float**`

```
| 1.0  2.0  3.0 |
| 4.0  5.0  6.0 |
| 7.0  8.0  9.0 |
```

I have this method that works on matrix as array:

```
float a(float* x, float* b, int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    float e = 0, de, yp;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        yp = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            yp += x[i*(n+1)+j] * b[j];
        de = fabs(x[i*(n+1)+n]-yp);
        e += (de*de);
    }
    return e;
}
```

And this one that in my intention should do the same thing:

```
float a(float **x, float **b, int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    float e = 0, de, yp;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        yp = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            yp += x[i][j] * b[j][0];
        de = fabs(x[i][j]-yp);
        e += (de*de);
    }
    return e;
}
```

Is there a smart way to compare the two methods without try to write two different representations of the same input and check if the output is the same in both?

Note:
the line `de = fabs(x[i*(n+1)+n]-yp);` in the firs method seems an error since I don't see what is supposed to do this line... I'm not the author of the monodimensional version of the method, so I don't know the real intention of author, I'm trying to adapt the code to work with multidimensional matrices, for this reason I have interpreted this line as `de = fabs(x[i*(n+1)+j]-yp);`, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: "without try to write 2 different representation of the same input and check if the output is the same in both?" - Why would you need any other way?  That's how functions are tested; given an input `x`, what is the output `y`.  What's so hard about feeding them two sets of data and comparing the result?

Comment: I trust you were careful how you allocated memory to get `**x` to work in the way you intended… you have to have created an array of pointers to the first value in each row of the 2D matrix. If you don't know what I am talking about then I suspect your second code will not work as you intended. Can you show the code that allocates memory for `x`, and how you call your second function?

Comment: The problem is that I have to do the same thing many times on at least 10 methods. Understand how to *see* the iterations in the first representation as array of array can safe me a lot of time.

Comment: @Floris the allocation is right and the method compile and returns me a value I have doubt about the iteration. (the first come from another program and both routine work on random values because of that I have to rewrite input properly many times if I don't find a better way to compare both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you had allocated memory properly, you are not indexing the first array in the way you intended. Look at these lines:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    yp = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        yp += x[i*(n+1)+j] * b[j];
```

You hope that this is the same thing as

```
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    yp = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        yp += x[i][j] * b[j][0];
```

But the equivalent of indexing a 2D array `x[i][j]` when you have a 1D array, if there are `n` elements per row, is done with

```
 yp += x[i*n + j];
```

There is no `+1`…

Comment: Ops, distraction, you are right.... but my main doubt however is in this line `de = fabs(x[i*(n+1)+n]-yp);` Do you think is right my 2D conversion here?

Comment: No I don't think so. More importantly - one j loop goes only to `<n-1` the other goes to `<n`. And in one case you are using the value of `j` after the loop while in the other you use `n`. That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: the line `de = fabs(x[i*(n+1)+n]-yp);` seems an error since I don't see what is supposed to do this line... (note that I'm not the autor of the monodimensional version of the method, so I don't know the real intention of author, I'm trying to adapt the code to work with  multidimensional matrix).for this reason I have interpreted this as `de = fabs(x[i*(n+1)+j]-yp);`

Comment: The code looks like it's taking the product of a vector and a matrix - but then does some strange subtraction that frankly looks like it should overflow past the end of the matrix (depending on the values of `m` and `n` when the first code is called). But I am pretty sure that the second code doesn't do the same thing as the first. Just print out the values of `i` and `j` in the second for each pass through the inner loop, and print the value of the index in the 1D case - you will see you are not even iterating the same number of times.

Comment: Note that the line you worry about happens after the `j` loop completes, so you are relying on the value of `j` after the end of the loop. If you treated `j` as a truly local variable (using `for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++) {` then it wouldn't even _exist_ when you get to that line. Really though - you need to understand what the code is doing that you are adapting or you are setting yourself up for hard-to-understand errors. I really worry that the original code may be "wrong".